# Can you create a DSYM file from a header?

Tags: c, header, debug-symbols

I am trying to debug a file that has had its symbols stripped. I have headers for the file, with offsets for each function, and was wondering if it was possible to create a DSYM file using these headers. I cannot set breakpoints on the offsets because the file is a plugin, so the functions are mapped to a different location in memory.

Comment: Which platform are you working on?  I see .dSYM directories on MacOS X, but not files.

Comment: Yes, they are technically directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, it is not.